# Network kernel issue dst overflow

Tags: linux, kernel

I am currently having a issue with my server, apperently after awhile, my network will slowdown and later stop working. It shows this:

Dst overflow

My kernel is 2.6.18-308.8.2.el5.028stab101.1 #1 SMP Sun Jun 24 20:25:35 MSD 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

With CentOS, also running OpenVZ with SolusVM

Any solutions?

Comment: wow, so much information... `cat /etc/redhat-release`

Comment: Here you go: CentOS release 5.8 (Final)

Comment: can you also provide additional info where you got "dst overflow" line? maybe there's more info there?

Comment: i get it after awhile, and it basicly renders the server unusable till a reboot.

Comment: Not sure how i can possibly fix that. Hope someone knows.

Answer (score 0):

apparently this is a know issue, you're going have to wait for vendor to fix it...

[Fedora: Re: kernel: dst cache overflow](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Fedora/2005-07/1175.html)

Comment: This post is 2005. So there has been NO fix for years?? Unlikely.

Comment: yeah, I noticed that as well they're talking about .11 yours is .18

Comment: I hope someone would know. This is a major pain.